# How to rearrange columns in a table in C#

Tags: c#

I have created a table "simple gate pass table".

I added some columns:
ID, Serial, Date, To, Description, Authorized By.

afterwards, I created this table and later I realized I needed to add 1 more column "From"

but now it won't let me Re-edit existing columns and neither it lets me arrange columns.

[image]

Comment: I'm getting no error, I just cant able to drag "From" Column to "Description column"

Comment: Why would you want to do this? SQL Server does not allow to _physically_ reorder column: you'll need to re-create your table with the desired "layout" and then import existing data from the old table.

Comment: I wanted to know if it was possible...
alright thanks.

Comment: @Fawad there is a setting, which restricts you from accidently dropping and recreating the table. Uncheck it and you can drop and recreate the table with different column order.

Comment: @kanchirk can you tell me where it is?

Comment: @Fawad Check this https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/956176

Answer (score 1):

This is MSSQL-related question and it has nothing to do with C#.

---

IIRC MSSQL does not allow you to neither rearrange column order nor add column after/before any other. You can only drop column or add one (at the end of the table). If you want to select/display data in some specific order use a `SELECT` clause with appropriate order, e.g.:

```
SELECT id, serial, date, from, to, description, authorized_by ...
```

By the way, `from` or `date` are not the very best choices for column names as they are reserved words in most SQL dialects.

Answer (score 0):

you can change order of columns in management studio as follows:

1. Right click on table name in object explorer and select Design. List
   of columns will open.
2. In the newly opened list of columns, left click and drag column name to the position you want.
3. Press ctrl+s to save.

Comment: database is .SDF and not .MDF still possible?

Comment: i am not sure. you can give it a try